# Determine where h(x) := x $\lvert x \rvert$ is differentiable from R to R.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine where h(x) := x $\lvert x \rvert$ is differentiable from R to R.

Not totally sure how to start this.

Much appreciation,

Jesse

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, even if it is not correct, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: If you really don't know how to start, you can maybe already share your thoughts. What do you already know about the problem? What do you think you might need, but maybe still don't see how to apply it, etc. This also helps people to see in which directions you were thinking and help you as good as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: A plot of x |x|]

If at all possible. The first thing to do is graph the function and see if it looks differentiable.
 Let $f(x) = x |x|$

Case 1. If $x > 0$, then $f(x) = x^2$, which is differentiable.
So $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$

Case 2. If $x < 0$, then $f(x) = -x^2$, which is differentiable. So $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(-\infty, 0)$

Case 3. If $x = 0$, then the derivative as $x\rightarrow 0^+=0$ and the derivative as $x\rightarrow 0^-=0$. So $f'(0) = 0$.

Hence f is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Note that $h(x) = x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $h(x) = -x^2$ otherwise. Can you check if this is continuous? Does it have a derivative?

Answer (score -1):

The only possible place where $h(x)$ may fail to be differentiable is $x=0$.  So consider 
$$lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x|x|}{x}.$$
Does this limit exist? If so, $h(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.